# How to add other codecs to the dialog window?

Tags: video, video-codecs, vfw

When I call dlg window with video formats list from VFW (WM_CAP_GET_VIDEOFORMAT), then I have 2 positions only, one of those - MJPG (Motion JPG), when selected, as a result, makes video capture as black screen, what means - it doesn't work, but selectable.
YUY2 works ok, and I know how to manage it.

[image: DLG_GET_VIDEOFORMAT]

From other side, if I see the list of all installed codecs, it has much more than just MJPG and YUY2

1. ICM  Microsoft RLE   MRLE    msrle32.dll 6.1.7601.17514
2. ICM  Microsoft Video 1   MSVC    msvidc32.dll    6.1.7601.17514
3. ICM  Microsoft    YUV    UYVY    msyuv.dll   6.1.7601.17514
4. ICM  Кодек Intel    IYUV IYUV    iyuv_32.dll 6.1.7601.17514 ICM  Toshiba
5. ICM YUV    Codec Y411    tsbyuv.dll  6.1.7601.17514
6. ICM  Кодек Cinepak, made by    Radius    cvid    iccvid.dll  1.10.0.13

---

ICM (Image Color Management) and there is RLE - bitmap compression of 8 bits.
And others. But the dialog shows only 2 (and MJPG is not workable).

How does it work? How to add other codecs to the dialog window, and how to make it activated from VFW? I tried SET_VIDEOFORMAT vainly.. only one - YUY2 is accepted and could be set.

Pls, tell me more about camera - driver - vfw COM Graph builder principles.
How can I add, say, ICM Microsoft RLE codec?

Comment: That list does not contain your installed codes. These are the video formats your Web can output!

Comment: This is related neither to [tag:directshow], nor to [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window shows encodings in which the camera itself can be set to deliver video. This does not include software codecs available that can process/convert the video feed. MJPG might not work (blackness) because of faulty driver, or because the picture is lost in further processing steps (decoder is unable to decode it for whatever reason).

The other codecs you discovered work separately from the camera source, you can use them in code to do the conversion or encoding. You might need to deal with pixel format/encoding fitting: the camera gives YUY2 and not every encoder would accept it directly, it might need something else, e.g. RGB.

Comment: Hi Roman, then WM_CAP_SET_VIDEOFORMAT message doesn't "ask" VFW to try to find the proper codec to convert from device specific format to user specific, right? Does it mean that VFW has less abilities than DirectShow? I think VFW has kind of intellect to understand my need and looks through installed codecs for proper conversion.

Comment: You are dealing with camera only, it does not do any conversions. VFW is API from times when getting frame at all was a success and there were no implicit software conversion magic in video capture that you did not do yourself. VFW has apparently way less abilities than DirectShow.